# Restart of Tomcat makes job run every time irrespective of timer in java

Tags: java, tomcat

I set the time at 7:45 but for every restart of my tomcat, the code gets executed irrespective of time.
Can anyone suggest me what I need to change.

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,7);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    System.out.println("current time = " + (currentDateTime.getTime()).toString());
    System.out.println("************First run set @ " + c.getTime() +"******************");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), c.getTime(), DAY);
}
class Task extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        doit() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want this job to run at 7:45am every day, but you're not keeping track of whether the job has already run for "today" or not. So when you start Tomcat, you get a new Calendar which says it is 2:30PM on 2015-Jan-08, and you then change it to 07:45AM on 2015-Jan-08, and tell the Timer to run at that time.

The Timer says "oh, gosh, I'm late!" and promptly runs the task right away since it is 2:30PM and it was supposed to run almost 7 hours ago. As the documentation for `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` says, "if the scheduled first time is in the past, then any 'missed' executions will be scheduled for immediate 'catch up' execution." (The Timer has no connection to any Timers that might have lived in previous JVM instances, so as far as this Timer is concerned, it has not yet run today.)

Your solution, then, is probably to check what time it is; if it's after 7:45, then add a day to your calendar so the first run time is 07:45AM on 2015-Jan-**09**.

A better solution would be to note somewhere more permanent when the last run time was, and adjust the next run time (on Tomcat startup) accordingly. This would take into account the scenario where Tomcat crashes at 07:40 and is restarted at 07:50.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = c.getTime();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Date taskTime = c.getTime();
    if (taskTime.before(now)) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        taskTime = c.getTime();
    }
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), taskTime, DAY);
```

As I said above, if Tomcat happens to be down at 07:45, the task won't run that day. If you can live with that, then this should be perfectly fine for you. Otherwise, you'll need to keep track of the last time the task ran and adjust accordingly.

Comment: It daily runs at 7:45 and gives me the notification, even after that due to other war files in the tomcat when i restart it, again the job runs and sends the notification. I just dont want that to run after 7:45AM daily. @dchsohl

Comment: Yes. Re-read what I wrote. When you restart Tomcat, the *new* Timer that results has no idea what the old Timer (pre-restart) did. So it runs again because as the docs say, **if the scheduled first time is in the past, then any 'missed' executions will be scheduled for immediate 'catch up' execution.** You just need to ensure that the scheduled first time is *always* in the future, that's all.

Comment: can you tell me how to schedule first time is always in the future. @dcsohl

Comment: I would have thought this to be pretty obvious, but I've adjusted my answer to include code. Please accept my answer if this works for you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the calendar pass the time zone you want to use, to be sure that the system uses the one you want.
This also makes the code more system independent.